# Mid 80's arcade top-down scrolling spaceship shooter with upgradable ship

Tags: identify-this-game, arcade

I used to play an arcade game back in 1987 (first year high school) and I can't remember what it was called. The screen scrolled from the top (very much like 1942) but you flew a spaceship.

Some defeated enemies dropped stars and collecting each one progressed an upgrade selection along the bottom of the screen with speed-up, different weapons, etc. When you had moved to the upgrade you wanted you selected it.

As you continued to select the same upgrade (for a weapon) your ship gained extra 'modules' and became wider, eventually reaching nearly full width of the screen — and being very powerful.

I have an idea the title had some sort of 'wing' connotation but that may be wrong. I'd love to play it again but without the name that's impossible.

Comment: I can't really see a computer mentioned, so isn't that rather a question for [Arquade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Sorry, it could be. I'm brand new here and don't know my way around.

Comment: @Raffzahn [Off-topic on Arqade](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7617/145997).

Comment: @wizzwizz4 and so its here.

Comment: @Raffzahn Do we have consensus on that? There are currently zero close-votes, and I don't _remember_ any meta discussions concluding off-topicness (only that Arqade shouldn't point people here).

Comment: Well, I didn't do a close as I expected a move. And yes, this is retro COMPUTING. Already questions about what game someone had on his C64 are kinda fringe - "which kind of whack-a-mole-game was located in my childhood arcade" questions seem way over the edge of computing. Gaming may be an application of computing, but not topic in itself. Remember that we even closed questions regarding the very first full fledged processor systems in cars as being off topic.

Comment: Maybe check /r/TipOfMyJoystick on Reddit and the #identify-a-game channel on the MobyGames Discord?

Comment: I think this is heading too far off topic here. Personally I feel "what was this software questions" are off topic and this is stretching too far. I think @ssokolow suggestions are a good idea instead.

Comment: You know you can set SE to ignore any tag if you do not like these questions. Personally, I love them, on topic or not.

Comment: How was this reopened with no computing content?

Comment: Video game identifications (tagged [story-identification] and [video-games]) have been answered at https://scifi.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like Slap Fight.

I only ever played it on the Commodore 64 but I believe there was an arcade version.

https://www.lemon64.com/?mainurl=https%3A//www.lemon64.com/games/details.php%3FID%3D2343

Comment: Almost definitely Slap Fight.

Comment: That's the one! I wasn't even close to the name (and it still doesn't sound familiar) but that is the game I played. Thank you! Now to somehow find a machine or a gameboard for it. Worst case I'm buying a C64 and finding a copy on there.

Comment: I had the same problem until I found it several years ago.  Remember playing it once as a kid when my brother’s friend brought it around one day.  Of course he took the disk home so once I turned off the C65, I couldn’t play it again.  :(

Answer (score 0):

This sounds rather like Gemini Wing, and is the right time period.
Screenshots are from http://www.shmups.com/reviews/geminiwing/index.html

[image]

However, this game doesn't have the changing ship mechanic you describe.

Another possibility is B-Wings / Battle Wings, where power ups change the shape and size of your ship as described.

Comment: B-Wings is close, very similar mechanic but does not have the power up 'bar' across the bottom. I'm now thinking there was an audible "wing up" as you selected a ship enhancement so perhaps "wing" wasn't in the name.